# XWalkView открытие ссылки обычным браузером

Tags: android

У меня следующее задание.

Мне нужно открыть ссылку на веб-сайте с помощью дефолтного браузера,а не в XWalkView.

У меня есть XWalkView элемент, который прогружает определённый Web-сайт.
На сайте есть ссылки, при нажатии на которые открывается другой веб-сайт в самом XWalkView.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку у меня открывалась она в стандартном браузере,а не в XWalkView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
xWalkView.setResourceClient(new XWalkResourceClient(xWalkView)
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(XWalkView view, String url)
    {
        final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        //
        // Запускаем браузер:
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(browserIntent);
        //
        // Возвращаем true, чтобы XWalkView не делал переход внутри себя:
        return true;
    }
});
```

[Метод `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`](https://crosswalk-project.org/apis/embeddingapidocs_v3/org/xwalk/core/XWalkResourceClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(org.xwalk.core.XWalkView,%20java.lang.String))